# How to check cron job particular user

Tags: linux, unix

recently I'm given the interview for the role of Devops interviewer asked me this question "How to check cron job particular user." but I'm able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) of `crontab` you will see you can execute the command:

```
crontab -u username -l
```

and this will list the cron records for particular user. Be aware you should be able to read the cron records for this user (in short you should be `root`)